# In Testcafe can we declare a variable in a testcase and use the same as an expected value for an assertion?

Tags: variables, testing, automated-tests, testcafe

I want to store an UI element as a variable in testcase and want to use the varible as an expected value for an assertion later to match  it with a similar text. But couldn't figure out a way.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

TestCafe does not support snapshot testing. We are discussing the possible implementation of this feature in this [thread](https://github.com/DevExpress/testcafe/issues/5282). You can follow it to be informed about our progress.